# the problem fog rendering has broken surface

Tags: smoke-simulation

I create a smoke fluid container in the scene. After a good simulation cache to disk, I use the container as a Particle emitter.
1. Because too many particles are emitted, the container is interspersed. Such as:[image]

2. When there is interspersed there will be broken surface. Preview of the rendering in blender will not appear as:[image]
3. But in the final output into the picture there will be problems such as:
   [image]

4.I also set the maximum transparency of the light path inside the rendering set to 300, such as:[image]

5. Then I added to the maximum 1024, it does not work. I do not know if you have a good solution to this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Try to increase the volume samples. I don't know the chinese characters, but the value on the bottom right (0) should be the maximal path length for volume rays. You should also increase the max path lenth (8), the top-right value. Does this help? Did you duplicate the domain object using the particle system?

Comment: Yes, I use a particle system to copy domain objects.